# Retrieve a post with its ACF repeater fields in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, theme-development, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

In a wordpress theme I am programming, I created a custom post type and its template. This custom post type displays a list thanks to advance custom fields that I attached to the post template. In fact, I used the "repeater" field of Advance custom fields pro. The user only has to insert items of the list when editing the post. I am trying to do the following: I want to display in two specific pages templates the post with all its custom fields (the list created through the repeater). I am not able to do that, I only can retrieve the "normal" fields of the post (the title, the content...). I created a snippet so you can look at my code.

```
<?php //the single of the post: ?>
<ul class='slider-partners'>
    <?php
    //slider partners
    if( have_rows('slider_partenaires_hp') ): //"slider_partenaires_hp" is the repeater field

        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('slider_partenaires_hp') ) : the_row();

            // display a sub field value
            echo "<li class='partenaire-slide'><img src='" . get_sub_field('logo_partner') . "'></li>"; //"logo_partner" is the item inside the repeater field

        endwhile;
    else :

        // no rows found

    endif;

    ?>
</ul>

<?php //the template of the page where I try to retrieve the above post:       
        $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'      => 'our-partners',
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order'          => 'DESC'
        )); 
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $the_query->the_post();

        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Could you please help me in calling a post with all its custom fields in two diferent pages ? Thanks

Comment: ACF is off-topic here

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
 $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => 'our-partners',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'order'          => 'DESC'
    )); 
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
        $the_query->the_post();
        if( have_rows('slider_partenaires_hp') ): //"slider_partenaires_hp" is the repeater field
            // loop through the rows of data
            while ( have_rows('slider_partenaires_hp') ) : the_row();
                // display a sub field value
                echo "<li class='partenaire-slide'><img src='" . get_sub_field('logo_partner') . "'></li>"; //"logo_partner" is the item inside the repeater field
            endwhile;
        else :
            // no rows found
        endif;
    endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

This has to work